# axios return 404 error while it works on postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

My code:

```
var axios = require("axios");
export default async function({ req, state, redirect }) {
   var token = getCookie("realtime_jwt_token", req);
   const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/checkToken", {
      token
   });
   console.log(response);
}
```

When i call my middleware like this whenever i try to access some specific page, i get an 404 error.

> Request failed with status code 404

I have tried the request on Postman and there it works fine.
The mode is set to universal 
Where is the mistake here?

Comment: try to compare these two requests by capturing them in something like Fiddler.

Comment: Best to include a screenshot of your postman request, but make sure you're POSTing on both clients

Comment: Get the content of the request from Postman and compare it with the requests you can see in DevTools (if you use Chrome)

Comment: Is the application listening on port 3000 the same one in which you have middleware? Maybe your application doesn't see this address (`localhost:3000`)?

Comment: You can look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51353658/reactjs-express-axios-post-returns-404-works-from-postman) . There is the